# HttpContext is not rexognized even after using System.web( It is used in the controller)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, frameworks

[image]

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Controller.HttpContext',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not in the controller directly, to access HttpContext here use property of filterContext:

```
filterContext.HttpContext
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FilterContext to access the HttpContext outside of your controller. The FilterContext class can get your HttpContext for the current request.

```
 HttpContext httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
```